# The use of the preposition "on" after "spend time" in context

Tags: prepositions

Do I have to use *on* in the following context?

> Besides spending time being with your family, what other thing do you spend time **on** doing?

If the sentence sounds akward with or without the *on*, how would build it so that it could sound well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your sentence, but the main focus of your question is on the final two words.

Basically, you don't need "on" *and* "doing" - use one or the other. You can spend time *on* something, you can also spend time *doing* something. "Spend time on" is an idiomatic way of referring to the usage of time. "Doing" is just one of many verbs that you could use instead.

The most natural way to phrase the question would be:

> Besides being with your family, what else do you spend time on?

- There is no need to say "spending time" twice.
- I would not say "thing" because not all uses of time are "things", making the question too specific. Also, your family is not a "thing", and saying "what other *thing*" suggests that they are.
- Likewise, I would not use "doing" in this context, because spending time with your family isn't really an activity.

You might say "what else do you spend time *doing*" if you were talking about activities, for example:

> Besides playing football, what else do you spend time doing?

Answer (score 1):

According to OALD: Spend :
1- sth **on** sth

> How long did you spend **on** your homework?

2-sth **doing** sth

> I spend too much time **watching** television.
>   I have spent years **trying** to learn Japanese.

3- sth **in doing** sth

> Most of her life was spent **in caring** for others.

what other thing do you spend time (**in doing**)/( **doing**)?